# Sonar throws error when encounter unicode in java

Tags: java, maven-2, unicode, sonarqube

i am trying to run sonar on our java code using a minimum maven pom.

I can run 3 project

When i encounter a project having unicode UTF-8  the sonar:sonar command fails!

```
INFO]  Sensor SquidSensor...
INFO]  Java AST scan...
INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR] BUILD ERROR
INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO] Can not execute Sonar

mbedded error: Got an exception - unexpected char: '\', file : D:\Sonar\Projects\AoGServices\src\main\com\mypackage\ao565svc\services\KommunikationPrµferenceOpretServiceBean.java, line : 34
INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the line 34 having a class name with  `"\u00E6"`

How can i tell sonar to work on the unicode ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but I think you may be able to fix this by adding the following to your POM:

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    ...
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

References:

- [POM Element for Source File Encoding](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/POM+Element+for+Source+File+Encoding)
- [Compiler plugin - compiler:compile](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html)